# why SSIS cant recognize dynamically variable set in XML config file for connection of child package?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a SSIS package. I use SSIS 2008 r2.It has parent package start package and it call 3 child package . i want to dynamically  set connection property of these child  packages and my connection strings then i use XML configuration file   and  add 3 variable to start package and set this variable in  expression of packages but when i run this package as file system in SQL server it show me this error .any tips or trick would be welcome .thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to be related to network drive mapping, a package running on a server would not be aware of the drive letter. Use the server path to connect to the package. Eg \server\TestSSIS\ArchiveConnectionFile.dtsx